# Reloading issue - background to foreground

Tags: flutter, reload

Reloading issue - background to foreground

I am developing an flutter application I am having an issue that my application goes to background and after few minutes if I open my app it starts reloading, imagine I am using the application after that I am using four applications in one by on after if I open my app it starts reloading

Comment: Could you paste your whole code so that I will give a feedback. I hope you call your api call after build method that's why its call again when you get back to your resume option